# Как мне добиться анимации такой

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Привет ребята есть вопрос по поводу вёрстки html css jquerry и т д, как мне добиться появления плавного бордера как на картинке при наведении, спасибо за внимание [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень сложно разглядеть анимацию на статичной картинке =)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.border {
  width: 50px;
  background: gray;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right-width: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all linear .2s;
}

.border:hover {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="border"></div>
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ТЕБЕ СЫРОК) ДАЙ БОГ ТЕБЕ СВЕЖЕГО СЫРКА В ХОЛОДИЛЬНИКЕ

Comment: @Houckz, ахах, всегда пожалуйста)